# liqpay/dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I have a "Liqpay" form that comes from the API and I have to make a POST request, this form is output to the console and is in the browser's designer panel, but for some reason it is not displayed on the page, but I do it through dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

I called this form in useState and wanted to output with dangerouslySetInnerHTML to a structure, but it just doesn't show up, even though everything worked before.